# Parameter is missing in Controllers#create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, restful-architecture

Im trying to make an app when an user can book a training hour.
When i try to create the book i recieve the following method:

> ActionController::ParameterMissing in BookingsController#create
>
> param is missing or the value is empty: booking

This is my booking controller:

```
class BookingsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :load_training,  only: [:create]

  def new
    @booking = Booking.new
  end

  def create
    @booking = @training.bookings.build(booking_params)
    @booking.user = current_user
    if @booking.save
      flash[:success] = "Book created"
      redirect_to training_index_url
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end


  def index
    @booking = Booking.all
  end


  def destroy
    @booking = Booking.find(params[:id])
    @booking.destroy
    flash[:success] = "Book deleted"
    redirect_to training_index_url
  end



private

  def booking_params
    params.require(:booking).permit(:user_id, :training_id)
  end

  def load_training
    @training = Training.find_by(params[:training_id])
  end
end
```

I dont know why it doesnt takes the user_id parameter into the booking, i noticed because i did puts @user in the create method and the result is nil. And when i did it with user i got a positive answer (id, hour, slots, etc)

This is my booking model:

```
class Booking < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :training
  default_scope -> { order(created_at: :desc) }
  validates :user_id, presence: true
  validates :training_id, presence: true



end
```

My routes rb:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  root 'static_pages#home'
  get    '/signup',               to: 'users#new'
  get    '/contact',              to: 'static_pages#contact'
  get    '/about',                to: 'static_pages#about'
  get    '/login',                to: 'sessions#new'
  post   '/login',                to: 'sessions#create'
  delete '/logout',               to: 'sessions#destroy'
  get    '/book',                 to: 'bookings#new'
  post   '/book',                 to: 'bookings#create'
  delete '/unbook',               to: 'bookings#destroy'


  resources :account_activations, only: [:edit]
  resources :password_resets,     only: [:new, :create, :edit, :update]
  resources :bookings,            only: [:create, :destroy]
  resources :training
  resources :users
end
```

New booking view:

```
<h1>Booking confirmation</h1>

<%= form_for (@booking) do |f| %>
  <%= f.submit "Book", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

I would like to now why the booking method doesnt retrieve the user_id parameter.

This is what i see during the post:

```
Started POST "/bookings" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-03-09 00:31:53 -0400
Processing by BookingsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"EUoo8M66O2XlRgeMoEsSqwH2i/EKKFzMMRsY9UilzcU+T+5n6/Gjx0abxlZ7nJlqgr5wsALtXW/UMf2Q01pNUg==", "commit"=>"Reservar"}
  Training Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "trainings".* FROM "trainings" LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 1]]
Completed 400 Bad Request in 2ms (ActiveRecord: 0.1ms)



ActionController::ParameterMissing (param is missing or the value is empty: booking):

app/controllers/bookings_controller.rb:36:in `booking_params'
app/controllers/bookings_controller.rb:9:in `create'
  Rendering /home/cesar/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.html.erb wi
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you post what you see being sent during the post in the terminal.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow... so in your form/view I see no fields for  `user_id` or `training_id`.  Have you simply forgotten to include them?

Comment: how should i add the training_id?

Answer (score 0):

Problem with you code is you are not sending `user_id` and `training_id` from your booking view.

You should have `user_id` which can be a hidden field and `training_id` for the training for which user opted for.

```
<%= f.hidden_field :user_id, value: current_user.id %>
```

You can have a list of trainings with multi select option if user can book multiple training at a time.

It user can book only one training in a single transaction, checkbox against every training should do the trick.

```
<ul>
  <% @trainings.each do |training| %>
      <li>
        <%= check_box_tag 'training_ids[]', training.id -%>
        <%= h training.name -%>
      </li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

When user submit this, you will get `user_id` as well as `training_ids` as `training_ids = ["1", "2", "3"]`

Comment: okay im kinda confused, im going to make it that the user can only has one reservation per day, where do i have to put the code that iterates the @training object? training index?

Comment: it gives me the error: undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass